# Why do "blind" and "deaf" have more semantic range than they seem to merit?

Tags: semantics

Thinking of sightedness and "hearingness" as real numbers on a scale of 0 to 1, why is it that "blind" and "deaf" mean < 0.5 rather than 0? It doesn't seem helpful to have the meaning of the word for "not having any of the ability at all" be diluted with "having less of the ability than most."

The Cambridge dictionary says deaf means ["unable to hear, either completely or partly"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/deaf) I admit that admit that blind in Cambridge simply says "unable to see," but I have seen it in common use to mean partially blind, as in the case of a certain Youtuber who is partially sighted and describes himself as blind (I can't think of his name at the moment).

Comment: Those terms only allow for a tolerance for some of the sense existing in medical definitions.  That's not general usage, though.  Laypeople all but exclusively use "deaf" and "blind" to mean completely hearingless or completely sightless.  If, as a  layperson, I want to say that you're "half-blind," that's what I say, or if I want to say you're "more than half-blind," then that's what I say. Do terms "merit" anything, though?

Comment: Hello, Johnny. Please add relevant attributed and linked references. I expect the words are polysemous and hypernymic (have conflicting definitions). // This situation is common in English. There are different definitions of 'hurricane'; my hurricane might not be called such by the people at the met office. Squares are probably only rectangles to mathematicians. We can't even agree on a single definition for 'word' here on ELU. And then there are big flies and small elephants.

Comment: https://www.nfb.org/sites/www.nfb.org/files/images/nfb/publications/fr/fr19/fr05si03.htm . Colloquial use of the word often precedes and lags scientific understanding.

Comment: Well, it can be dark, and it can be *dark* dark. Neither of these needs to be complete darkness.

Comment: @jimm101 Send me a reminder to like this if I get enough rep.

Comment: There are people who can only distinguish light and dark, others who can detect movement. To all intents and purposes they are blind, and I don't think there is a scale which defines the degree of utility.

Comment: Have you ever heard of the *euphemism* treadmill? Also, *blinded*, *blonde* and *to blend* imply a basic graded sense for that one at least. *blunt* hardly has any substantial superlative at all (except for Method Man and Redman); Ger *taub*, akin to *deaf* means as much, that is "numb; deaf". Also cp *dumb*, Ger *stumm* "mute", *stammer, mumble*, *stop*, *stub*, *stomped*, *stumped*, Ger *stumpf* "blunt" (as in *blunt force trauma*), Ger *stopfen* "to jam, plug, stuff", *verstopfte Ohren* "stuffed ears; deaf" etc. etc.

Comment: The health insurance once informed me they'd sponsor glasses only in case of blindness on both eyes. They surely see blindness as a matter of degree on a scale. I didn't know though and the letter didn't tell anyhow.

Comment: My cousin, aged 60, says "they want to call me 'visually impaired'. I'm BLIND. I've been blind all my life, it's too late to change now!"

Comment: Vectory, what's this _Ger_ thing you keep typing?

Comment: It's not "having less of the ability than most", it's "having too little of the ability for it to be usable in any practical sense". In a nonmedical situation it is not helpful to draw a distinction between 0 vision and 10% vision because both will still require a cane or guide dog to get around in public, etc. We don't want people second-guessing whether someone is "really" blind, like in the case of the bus driver who refused to accept the credentials of a friend of my mum who is blind and refused her the free travel she is legally entitled to - and yelled at her about "faking it".